# open and closed subsets in metric space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm reading John M. Lee's [Introduction to Topological Manifolds](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4419-7940-7). And I confused when I read the Appendix B for Metrics.

**Exercise** In each part below, a sunset $\mathit{S}$ of a metric space $\mathit{M}$ is given. In each case, decide whether $\mathit{S}$ is open, closed, both or neither.

(a) $\mathit{M} = \mathbb{R},\,and\,\mathit{S}=[0,1).$

(b) $\mathit{M} = \mathbb{R},\,and\,\mathit{S}=\mathbb{N}.$

(c) $\mathit{M} = \mathbb{Z},\,and\,\mathit{S}=\mathbb{N}.$

(d) $\mathit{M} = \mathbb{R}^2,\,and\,\mathit{S}$ is the set of points with rational coordinates.

(e) $\mathit{M} = \mathbb{R}^2,\,and\,\mathit{S}$ is in the unit disk {$(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2<1$}.

(f) $\mathit{M} = \mathbb{R}^3,\,and\,\mathit{S}$ is in the unit disk {$(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3:z=0$ and $x^2+y^2<1$}.

(g) $\mathit{M} = $ { $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:x>0 $ and $ y>0 $}, and { $\mathit{S}={(x,y)\in \mathit{M}:x^2+y^2 \le 1}$}.

Can anyone give me some ideas? My current answer is

(a) neither

(b) closed

(c) neither

(d) neither

(e) open

(f) neither

(g) neither

I just found two criteria for the issue about open/closed subsets in this section. They are,

$\bullet$ A subset A $\subseteq$ M is said to be an **open subset of M** if it contains an open ball around each of its points.

$\bullet$ A subset A $\subseteq$ M is said to be an **closed subset of M** if M \ A is open.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not so much interested in the answers you got than for the reasons you got them.  Why do you thinkg $S= \mathbb N\subset \mathbb Z = M$ is neither open nor closed.

Comment: I don't agree with c) and g). The integers are discrete so every subset is open and for part g) you can easily check that the subset is closed. (since it can be written as the intersection of a (in $\mathbb{R}^2$) closed subset with the set M.)

Comment: The underlying issue here is connectedness.

Comment: c) and g) are indeed both wrong.  One thing that might be useful would be if $M' \subset M$ and $S' = S\cap M'$ then if $S$ is open/closed in $M$ then $S'$ is open/closed in $M'$.  Pf: If an open ball $B$ is a subset of $S$ then $B\cap M'\subset B\cap S$. And if $B\subset M\setminus S$ then $B\subset (M\setminus S)\cap M'=M'\setminus S$.  (That will help with g).

Answer (score 1):

I'll just critique c).

$S = \mathbb N$ and $M = \mathbb Z$

Let $k \in S=\mathbb S$.  Let the open ball of radius $\frac 12$ around $k$ be $B_{\frac 12} k = \{x \in M=\mathbb Z| d(x,k)< \frac 12\}= \{x \in \mathbb Z: |x\in (k-\frac 12, k+\frac 12)\}= \{x \in\mathbb Z| k-\frac 12 < x < k+\frac 12\} = \{k\}$.

So the open ball of radius $\frac 12$ around $k$ is ... the set $\{k\}$.  That is $k$ is the only element in the ball and $k$ is in the ball.  .... Weird, but true.  It doesn't *seem* very "ball-like" and it doesn't seem very "open-like" but it is the definition.

And $\{k\} \subset S = \mathbb N$.

So $S$ is open.

.....

Now is it closed.  Well $\mathbb Z\setminus \mathbb N = \{$ negative integers along with $0\}$.  That's open by the same argument.

SO $S$ is both.